# Count total without duplicate records

Tags: sql

I have a table  that contains the following columns: TrackingStatus, Year, Month, Order, Notes

I need to calculate the total number of tracking status for each year and month.

For example, if the table contains the following orders:

| TrackingStatus | Year | Month | Order | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | 2020 | 1 | 33 |  |
| F | 2020 | 1 | 33 | DFF |
| E | 2020 | 2 | 36 | xxx |
| A | 2021 | 3 | 34 | X1 |
| A | 2021 | 3 | 34 | DD |
| A | 2021 | 3 | 88 |  |
| A | 2021 | 2 | 45 |  |

The result should be:

•   Tracking F , year 2020, month 1 the total will be one (because it's the same year, month, and order).
•   Tracking A , year 2021, month 2 the total will be one. (because there is only one record with the same year, month, and order).
•   Tracking A , year 2021, month 3 the total will be two.  (because there are two orders within the same year and month).

So the expected SELECT output will be like that:

| TrackingStatus | Year | Month | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | 2020 | 1 | 1 |
| E | 2020 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 2021 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 2021 | 3 | 2 |

I was trying to use group by but then it will count the number of records which in my scenario is wrong.

How can I get the total orders for each month without counting “duplicate”  records?

Thank you

Comment: can you share your current query?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this by grouping by all these 3 columns, what have tried, what's the current output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `COUNT DISTINCT` aggregation function, whereas the `COUNT` allows you to count the values, but the DISTINCT condition will allow each value only once.

```
SELECT TrackingStatus,
       Year,
       Month,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Order) AS Total
FROM tab
GROUP BY TrackingStatus,
         Year,
         Month
ORDER BY Year, 
         Month
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cKhcyEnzafUbB9638HQMEk/0) you can find a tested solution in a MySQL environment, though this should work with many DBMS.